# join 2-d list with braces instead of bracketspython

Tags: python

I want to feed python output to a latex script, but latex define 2-d array with braces, python use brackets. so I wish to print output from python but convert brackets to braces!

For example:
Print below 2-d list:

```
mylst = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
print(mylst)
```

Output

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

How can I get a string with braces instead as below:

```
{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}
```

Comment: What are you looking to do? Do you actually just want a string like `s = your_answer(mylst)` or do you want a list type that, when printed, would use curly braces instead of square brackets? Mind you, printing something isn't 'getting its string value', it's just printing its representation. Note that using curly braces on a list is generally a bad idea, since it reminds python programmers of sets or dictionaries and many other programmers would expect something like a dictionary as well, so I'm no sure why you need this in the first place...

Comment: *"Print below 2-d list will output a string"* You are terribly wrong. Why do you reach to the conclusion that output is a string?

Comment: If you are purely interested in the output formatting, simple `str.replace` will do the job: `str([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]).replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}')`.

Comment: @Austin updated my question with more details! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` doesn't exactly "output a string", rather it writes a string representation of the provided expression to standard out. Often that's identical to what you'd get if you executed `s = str(<some expression>)` but definitely not always, especially for more complex types.

If you just want to create a string that looks like your example and print it, you could do something with a function like this:

```
def list_in_braces(xs):
    return f'{{{",".join(str(x) if not isinstance(x, list) else list_in_braces(x) for x in xs)}}}'


mylst = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
print(list_in_braces(mylst))
```

Of, if the f-string is confusing:

```
def list_in_braces(xs):
    return '{' + ','.join(str(x) if not isinstance(x, list) else list_in_braces(x) for x in xs) + '}'
```

You can also do what @Chris suggests in the comments, but that has some other limitations and gotchas (like you cannot have brackets anywhere else in the values):

```
print(str(mylst).replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}'))
```

You'd get spaces in it though, because that's how Python prints a list. To could strip those out too:

```
print(str(mylst).replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}').replace(' ',''))
```

A bit messy for my taste. Note that using curly braces on a list is generally a bad idea, since it reminds python programmers of sets or dictionaries and many other programmers would expect something like a dictionary as well, so I'm no sure why you need this in the first place...

Comment: Note that both the functional solution and the replacement solution works for any level of nested list, not just the 2d example.

Comment: Awesome, the f-string is great!